# What does self = None do?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, python-internals, python-asyncio

I'm reading [the source code of the incoming `asyncio` package](http://code.google.com/p/tulip/source/browse/asyncio/events.py#37).  Note that at the end of the method, there is a `self = None` statement.  What does it do?

```
def _run(self):
    try:
        self._callback(*self._args)
    except Exception as exc:
        msg = 'Exception in callback {}{!r}'.format(self._callback,
                                                    self._args)
        self._loop.call_exception_handler({
            'message': msg,
            'exception': exc,
            'handle': self,
        })
    self = None  # Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs.
```

I thought it would erase the instance, but the following test doesn't suggest so:

```
class K:
    def haha(self):
        self = None

a = K()
a.haha()
print(a) # a is still an instance
```

Comment: Maybe the question should be "why can setting `self` to `None` break cycles? what cycles?"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It simply clears the local reference to `self`, making sure that if an exception occurs the reference passed to `self._loop.call_exception_handler()` is the only remaining reference and no cycle has been created.

This is still needed here because the local namespace is referenced by the exception traceback; it will ***not*** be cleared up when the function exits as there is a reference to the locals alive still.

This is documented in the [`sys.exc_info()` function documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) with a warning:

> **Warning**: Assigning the *traceback* return value to a local variable in a function that is handling an exception will cause a circular reference. This will prevent anything referenced by a local variable in the same function or by the traceback from being garbage collected. Since most functions don’t need access to the traceback, the best solution is to use something like `exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]` to extract only the exception type and value. If you do need the traceback, make sure to delete it after use (best done with a `try ... finally` statement) or to call `exc_info()` in a function that does not itself handle an exception.

Because `tulip` handlers form a fundamental framework class the code handles the traceback circular reference case by removing `self` from the local namespace instead, as it cannot guarantee that the `_callback` or `call_exception_handler` functions will clear up their references.

In CPython, objects are destroyed when their reference count drops to 0, but a cyclic reference (a series of objects referencing themselves in a cycle) will never see their reference count drop to 0. The garbage collector does try to break such cycles but it cannot always do this or not fast enough. Explicitly clearing references avoids creating cycles.

For example, if there is a `__del__` method, the garbage collector will not break a cycle as it won't know in what order to break a cycle safely in that case.

Even if there is no `__del__` method (which a framework class should never assume will not be the case) it's best to not rely on the garbage collector eventually clearing cycles.

Comment: Could you give an example of such a cyclic reference?

Comment: I still don't get it...  I mean, if the statement `self = None` is hit, then obviously the end of the method will be hit, in which case the local reference will drop out of scope anyway, so why do we need `self = None`?

Comment: @DerekChiang: no, because there is a live traceback when an exception occurs, holding the local namespace alive.

Comment: @msvalkon: anything that references an object directly or indirectly will do. `self.ref = self` is the simplest example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't understand, isn't there still a circle, ie. `self`->`_loop`->`self`, event after we remove the reference to `self` from `locals()`?

Comment: @satoru: perhaps, but at least the `self->call_exception_handler->exc->__traceback__->f_locals->self` loop is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this line is introduced in [revision 496](https://code.google.com/p/tulip/source/diff?spec=svnf8cbfd31aeba1cf6c52a72bab0d96740162128a8&old=67e230e26901e88783f6b24979e6585b350cd7d3&r=f8cbfd31aeba1cf6c52a72bab0d96740162128a8&format=unidiff&path=%2Ftulip%2Fevents.py) by Guido.

At this revision, the function that corresponded to `_run` is [run](https://code.google.com/p/tulip/source/browse/tulip/events.py?r=f8cbfd31aeba#49):

```
def run(self):
    try:
        self._callback(*self._args)
    except Exception:
        tulip_log.exception('Exception in callback %s %r',
                            self._callback, self._args)
    self = None  # Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs.
```

`tulip_log` is just a normal logger: `logging.getLogger("tulip")`.

Under the hood, `Logger.exception` stores the result of `sys.exc_info()` in `LogRecord`, but the record object doesn't persist after the `exception` call.

To verify that `logging.exception` doesn't cause reference cycle, I did the following experiment:

```
import time

import logging

class T:
    def __del__(self):
        print('T.__del__ called')

    def test(self):
        try:
            1 / 0
        except Exception:
            logging.exception("Testing")


def run():
    t = T()
    t.test()
    # t is supposed to be garbaged collected


run()

time.sleep(10) # to emulate a long running process
```

This is the result:

```
$ python test.py 
ERROR:root:Testing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in test
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
T.__del__ called
```

The object `t` is garbage collected as expected.

So, I don't think that `self = None` assignment is necessary here.

Comment: The same commit adds `self = None` in several locations, because it is good practice for a framework to do so, not because the codebase *in isolation* exhibits a circular reference.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you please show me an example when circular references are generated? Probably with `_callback`?

Comment: I haven't yet studied the tulip / asyncio library; I don't know the design intentions nor if the commit you studied was a Work in Progress (e.g. not yet the complete library even at the time). And the `logging` library allows you to register custom handlers and formatters; don't just go by the default codebase there.  Unfortunately, I don't have the time right now to build a sample case ATM (this comment comes courtesy of a smartphone over a 3G connection).